# ZF2 : paramaters coming from route are cleared after submitting a form

Tags: zend-framework2, routes, zend-form2

I'm using `AbstractTableGateway` and `HydratingResultset` to do db operations. (with BjyProfiler)
when i post my form data with add action it works, but edit action doesn't work. when i make a bind it works, but i m redirected to the add page because submitting the form resets paramaters coming from route.

here is my code for `editAction()` (same with Album editAction())

```
        $id = (int)$this->params()->fromRoute('id');
        if (!$id) {
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('voyage', array('action'=>'add'));
        }
        $voyage = $this->getVoyageTable()->getVoyage($id);

        $form = new VoyageForm($this->getTypeVoyageTable());
        $form->bind($voyage);
        $form->get('submit')->setAttribute('value', 'Edit');

        $request = $this->getRequest();
        if ($request->isPost()) {
            $form->setData($request->getPost());
            if ($form->isValid()) {
                $this->getVoyageTable()->saveVoyage($voyage);

                // Redirect to list of voyages
                return $this->redirect()->toRoute('voyage');
            }
        }

        return array(
            'id' => $id,
            'form' => $form,
        );
    }
```

and my table :

```
class VoyageTable extends AbstractTableGateway
{
    protected $table ='voyages';

    public function __construct(Adapter $adapter)
    {
        $this->adapter = $adapter;
        $this->resultSetPrototype = new HydratingResultSet();
        $this->resultSetPrototype->setObjectPrototype(new Voyage());
        $this->initialize();
    }
[...]
```

Can sombody help me? How can i fix this problem ? Thanks.

Comment: Are you actually setting the form action attribute in your view? If your routes are similar to the tutorial, you should have something like `<?php $form->setAttribute('action', $this->url('voyage', array('id' => $id, 'action' => 'edit'))); ?>` in edit.phtml, I'm guessing you're missing the `id` parameter.

Comment: yes i m setting it like you do
`<h1><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($title); ?></h1>
<?php $form = $this->form;
      $form->prepare();
  $form->setAttribute('action', $this->url('voyage', array('action' => 'edit')));
  $form->setAttribute('method', 'post');
  echo $this->form()->openTag($form);?>...`
i'm getting action id before submitting because bind function works when we click edit button. but when i submit the form i'm losing the id which redirects me to the add page.

Comment: You're missing the `'id' => $id` key/value pair in this line `$form->setAttribute('action', $this->url('voyage', array('action' => 'edit')));`. See my earlier comment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to inform the form about the hydrator since ClassMethods is not the default

```
 $form->setHydrator(new ClassMethods());
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. problem is resolved. see the comments.